# How to use custom Methods in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have the following issue: I am currently working on a ASP .net core entity framework backend and have the problem that I need to use a Custom Method in LINQ Query and getting a error when doing this. I
researched and found out that it is possible to write custom functions, that will be translated to sql, but I think that there is not a big scope for doing this. (e.g: SQL will not be able to use Libaries and hash strings).

Another way that I have heard of ist to convert my Database to a Enumberale and then apply my Custom Methods on it, which works, but is not that performant, because I am saving my whole Database in my memory, which gets very slow when having a huge amount of data. So my question is, if there is a performant solution to perform custom methods in LINQ queries?

My detailed problem is, that I have saved my salted passwords hashed in my database and when someone want s to log in to his account I have to compare the password in the database with the salt + user password input, that has to get hashed in my where clause. It would work if I wouldnt use salts, because then, I would only have to hash the user input, which is not column of the database.

Comment: You should get the salt and hashed password from the database, then hash the user input in code and compare with the existing hash. No need to send complicated code to the database. It also may be that the hashing is intentionally not performant to prevent brute-force attacks.

Comment: Run a stored procedure in database to do checking.   What type of database are you using?

Comment: madoxdev's answer covers it: Why would you want to compute something like a hash in the Linq query? When storing hashed values like passwords you save the Salt and the Hashed value to the database record. You do *not* store the unencrypted value, then try and hash both ends of the equation in the query or something like that.

Comment: Please look at my answer. @jdweng I am using MySQL as a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is - calculate the hash and salt in the backend, and use the computed hash in your WHERE statement. In this case you don't need to call your methods from SQL equally you don't need to pull entire db (or table) into memory to compute hash.

As I don't know your code, the pseudo-code approach would be:

```
    var user = service.GetUserByEmail(email);
if (user == null) {
//Invalid User
}
    var hash = ComputeHash(user.Salt, inputPwd);
    
 if(user.PasswordHash == hash) {
//User is logged in
} else {
//Invalid Password or email
}
```

Comment: I know whats to be done, but I get an error when I try to hash the current salt + the users input password in the where clause, be LINQ will translate it in SQL.

Comment: var result =  _context.Users.
                             .Where(e => (e.UserMail.ToUpper().Equals(data.Mail.ToUpper())
                              && e.UserPasswort.Equals((CreateHash(e.UserSalt + 
                              data.Password)))))
                             .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: look at my code please, I am getting entire user from the db, then do the hash calculation not on context (only passing data for that user), and then I am comparing if what I computed is equal to what is saved into db. While you are trying to do all of that on the Cotext, and this is the reqson it won't work

Comment: Okay thanks for that solution, my approach was not the best.